# Image not displaying after cache in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, caching

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvAb5.jpg)
I cached my database query that contain image string. When i create data in the database, the query runs successfully but image does not display.

i have gone through other questions but none is related to my question.

Please, before you vote me down, understand my question.

Before i cached my database query, images are displaying perfectly. Pages that where not cached like show, images display normal but index that was cached does not display image.

##### `controller.php`

```
public function index()
{
    
    $duplex = Cache::rememberForever('duplex', function () {
        return Property::where('buildingtype_id', '4')->simplePaginate(5);
    });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4WEs.jpg)com/2OIOi.jpg

index.blade.php

```
<div>
  
  <x-heading3>3 BEDEROOM FLAT</x-heading3>
      
  @if($bedroom3->count()) 
       @foreach($bedroom3 as $bedroom3)
       
            <a href = "/pages/{{$bedroom3->id}}">
              <x-indexdiv>

                        <x-image-card>
                        <img src="{{asset('storage/' .$bedroom3->SittingRoom)}} class="card-img-top" >
                        
                        </x-image-card>
                  
                    <div class=" w-auto py-2">
                        <x-fonthead>Rent:</x-fonthead> <x-fontbody> {{$bedroom3->amount}} </x-fontbody>
                        <a href = "/states/{{$bedroom3->state->id}}">
                          <x-fonthead>State:</x-fonthead> <x-fontbody>{{$bedroom3->State->name}}</x-fontbody>
                        </a>
                        
                        <x-fonthead> LGA:</x-fonthead> <x-fontbody> {{$bedroom3->Area->name}}</x-fontbody> 
                       <x-fonthead>Agent Name: </x-fonthead><x-fontbody>{{$bedroom3->Agent->firstname}}</x-fontbody> 
                    </div>
                  </x-indexdiv>
            </a>
            @endforeach
@endif
</div>
```

I tried to open images on a browser to compare the links. I found out that cached database image has an extension (%20class=) added to it. If i remove this extension, the image show correctly.

Image link from cached database query

http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/apartments/BKvTScbWZf4A4zaUEPha6E3IRRPQbCsrpUcp7CCz.jpg%20class=

Image link from uncached database query
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/apartments/DZpFDoX13A8dQFLHfrXImHc6l1N9zBEchPig0Nc3.jpg

Is there a way this can help in solving my problem?

```
Saving image file
```

'SittingRoom'=> request()->file('sittingroom')->store('apartments'),

Comment: So you said initially that when you cache the query and add data afterwards? Other pages would work because query might written to fetch data for those link won't be cached forever right?

Comment: @Ali, I added an image. If you look at the image, you will see that other details are showing but that of image is not. if i want to see the full details of the apartment that (show method) the image will display. I did not cache show method.

Comment: Can you show me your blade code or vue component code where you are printing that image string? Also please verify in your network call that your image string is included and not null.

Comment: @Ali, i have updated my question. Please, check if you have any suggestion or solution.

Comment: `%20` normally that happens when you have space in the you saved file name. You have to correct your file name also change the function that is uploading the file, while uploading the file replace spaces with "_" or "-". Then you will for sure be able to fix this issue.

Comment: `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $request->file(‘sittingroom’)); ` the reason of using this is your are getting file name and not sanitizing white spaces.

Comment: @Ali, thanks so far. I used store() to save image. Laravel automatically generated name for the image.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

First, I comment out the cache and then got my values by just database query. This worked for some of the queries but not all.

Second, I looked at my view,{{asset('storage/' .$bedroom3->SittingRoom)}} there is a space between storage and the name of the image. I closed the space.

Third, in my image tag, i called a class="card-img-top" when there is no card. so I removed this class.

Then everything works find